# Text formatting for content editable div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a popup text formatting tools for content editable tags.

I'm getting the popup which displays the formatting buttons. While executing the `document.execCommand(tags,false,null)` I'm not getting the desired formats. I guess the formatting commands are not executing the values to the current content editable `div`. I've included the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwrfq5t6/).

My function declared by to exec command:

```
function nitspopupeditor(key, edittag) { //Function to format editable items.
    if (edittag) {
        document.execCommand(edittag, false, null);
        $('key').focus();
    }
};
```

Right now I've included only bold and italics in HTML just to check whether its working or not.

Comment: Updated JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nitishkmr09/c56hzmmt/ please help me out guys...